# Uniqueness of Session ID in a Distributed environment?

Tags: spring, session, spring-session

We are using Spring Session (backed up with pivotal Gemfire) for our Spring Boot applications running in an Distributed environment.

In such a distributed environment,

> does Spring Session ensure that a unique session id is used for new
>   sessions being created across different JVMs ?

Answer (score 1):

Just reviewing old SO posts for *Spring Session* *Pivotal GemFire* support, so my apologies your question never got answered in a timely manner.

In a nutshell, *Spring Session* uses the [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class to generate "unique" Session IDs. For instance, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/AbstractGemFireOperationsSessionRepository.java#L380), or more generally, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/MapSession.java#L66).

NOTE: *Spring Session Data Redis* support [uses/wraps](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java#L682) the `MapSession` class to store Session state in Redis, by default.

There are appears to be a lot of [discussion](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Are%20UUIDs%20unique%20across%20JVMs) about the effectiveness, or rather uniqueness, of `UUID` across JVMs in a cluster.  This [one in particular](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1326404?tstart=0), though dated, caught my attention as it originated from the Oracle Java community forums.

However, keep in mind that it is your application(s) use of *Spring Session* that ultimately determines whether Session IDs are unique; i.e. it is not dependent on the number of nodes in a GemFire cluster since individual GemFire nodes are not generating the Session ID (applications using *Spring Session* are).

Therefore, if only 1 application (probably not likely in the Microservices state of the world) is ever present with *Spring Session* in use, then the UUIDs are probabilistically guaranteed to be unique.  Even then, based on [references](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Are%20UUIDs%20unique%20across%20JVMs) available, it seems highly unlikely that 2 or more "application" nodes employing Spring Session will ever generate IDs that collide (though, (almost?) anything is possible ;-).

Though, I suppose if it is of paramount concern/importance, following with the beautiful tradition of *Spring*, it would be a simple matter to **extend** the `GemFireOperationsSessionRepository` and override the [createSession()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/GemFireOperationsSessionRepository.java#L110-L112) method, calling the appropriate `GemFireSession` [constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/AbstractGemFireOperationsSessionRepository.java#L384-L388) to pass the desired Session ID in.

However, in all cases (GemFire, Redis, etc), the Session ID uniqueness problem is agnostic of underlying, backing data store.

Hope this helps...

Cheers!